# Different variables with same name in dom-repeat template

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have the following partial:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" repeat="{{myItems}}">
  One:   <paper-input type="number" value="{{myValue1}}"></paper-input>
  Two:   <paper-input type="number" value="{{myValue2}}"></paper-input>
  Three: <paper-input type="number" value="{{myValue3}}"></paper-input>
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[_show(myValue1)]]">
      Four: <paper-input value="{{myValue4}}></paper-input>
  </template>
</tempalte>
```

`myItems` is an array with 4 elements, so, I can see 12 `paper-inputs`.
The problem is when I enter some text into first `paper-input`, the text appears into others `paper-inputs` (the firsts of each iteration).

Is there any way to bind different variables into `dom-repeat` template?

Answer (score 1):

EDITED to use indices/ordinals instead of array values:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" 
          items="{{myItems}}" as="item">
  One:   <paper-input type="number" value="{{item.1}}"></paper-input>
  Two:   <paper-input type="number" value="{{item.2}}"></paper-input>
  Three: <paper-input type="number" value="{{item.3}}"></paper-input>
  <template is="dom-if" 
            if="[[_show(item.1)]]">
      Four: <paper-input value="{{item.4}}></paper-input>
  </template>
</template>
```

Comment: `myItems` is only an array with numbers form 1 to N, so, I can not do `item.myValue1`. `myValue` is a property.

Comment: then you should be able to do item.1, item.2, item.3, etc.

Comment: yep, codeMonkey is right with his approach. there is no way you can do it like you want @Amparo . You have 2 options. don't use dom-repeat and just write all inputs or edit your array to be an array of objects with some values inside it.

Comment: Kuba, I get errors when I try to use `item.myValue1`. Could you put any example in jsfiddle?

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect what we're discussing.